# Storing AlamoFire Response

Tags: swift, alamofire

I can't seem to store the response from AlamoFire into my variable jsondata1. I've tried making it type ANY, and type JsonData, still the variable returns a nil value.

```
class Data {

let parameters = ["test": "test1"]
var jsondata1: Any?  

func GetData() {
    AF.request("my url", parameters: 
     parameters).responseDecodable(of: [JsonData].self ) { 
     (response) in
        
        self.jsondata1 = response.value

       // debugPrint(response)
       // print(jsondata1)
    }
}

}

class Testing : Data {

func AnnualTesting() {
    
    debugPrint(jsondata1)
}

}
```

Comment: Where do you call `GetData()`?

Comment: @vadian, in the view controller:

Comment: The value is stored correctly. Uncomment the `debugPrint` line. Be aware that the AF  request works asynchronously. And don't name a custom class `Data`. It could interfere with the Foundation struct `Data`

Comment: @vadian It doesn't seem like the value is stored...it just brings back nil.

Comment: Did you remove the `//`? You have to process the data in the closure due to its asynchronous behavior or add a completion handler.

Comment: @vadian Yes, uncommented the line, still returning nil value for jsondata1. I think it may have to do with the type of jsondata1?

Comment: Yes, then the decoding process fails. Get the DecodingError and print it.

Comment: @vadian No just checked, the decoding works. It converts the keys in the Json to the variables I specified.

Comment: @vadian   [Result]: success([AlamoTest.JsonData